# pager script missing the first entry

Tags: javascript, html

I found this pager online, it works fine, except that when i bind the data to my table it is skipping the first record everytime i use it. Can any of the experts see it?

```
function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;
    this.inited = false;

    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {        
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to)  
                rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            else
                rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }

    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }

        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';

        this.currentPage = pageNumber;
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';

        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
        this.showRecords(from, to);
    }   

    this.prev = function() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1)
            this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
    }

    this.next = function() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
            this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
        }
    }                        

    this.init = function() {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1); 
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
    }

    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }
        var element = document.getElementById(positionId);

        var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> &#171 Prev </span> | ';
        for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++) 
            pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> | ';
        pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next &#187;</span>';            

        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
    }
}
```

for example my records are

```
house
apartment
condo
```

when i use the pager it is only showing

```
apartment
condo
```

PS: I tried modifying it myself but or it would not work, or I would mess the paging. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `+ 1` from this line:

```
var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
```

The pages use 1-based indexing, but the rows in the table use 0-based.

Comment: Although, it still skips the first item, this improved it because the last page on the pager was bringing back the results of the first page. But it still skips the first item